# Using (Flex)Sprite objects in an MXML-based application

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

`Canvas.addChild()` insists any `DisplayObject` added implements `IUIComponent`. But I don't want my core graphics engine dependent on Flex. Is there an obvious/common way around this, to have simple graphical objects like Sprites & Shapes in a Flex application? The individual `DisplayObject` children I want to add as children represent objects in a game world, like a spaceship or a missile or a horse...

Not sure if `Canvas` is the most appropriate container, perhaps `Group` or another class is optimal for a game-engine... example MXML & AS3 code showing a skeleton setup is most welcome. I'm targeting Flex4 & Flash 10, but Flex3/Flash9 solutions are still of interest.

Comment: Are there any specific reasons why you want to use the Flex framework as opposed to developing a pure AS3 project where all of the above would be avoided? You're asking for a skeleton setup with MXML & AS3 , but it's not really clear why you require MXML at all.

Comment: Lets me create UI without having to have an artist, or learn CS4. It's entirely plausible to use a pure AS3 engine in an MXML-based application. I've developed a MMORPG using this setup before and it worked out nicely. But it's personal preference, Flex is quite capable and it must be possible to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of canvas, you can use `UIComponent` as it does not have the IUIComponent implementor requirement. Then `addChild()` your sprites to that.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to _avoid_, making all my objects `UIComponent`. Or are you suggesting something else?

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify the answer.

Comment: OK, I see. I can have an inner container the same size as the main MXML, for instance. In Flex4 I want to use `Group` rather than canvas... but the idea is the same.